# RESTFUL --> Check if a item is Active?

Tags: rest, servicestack

I am writing a RESTful Service and one of the endpoints would be checking if a resource is active.

I am struggling to get the RESTful resource name to be as per standard

What should be my Route  GET /api/v1/items/{itemid}/isActive -- ? All I am doing (or want to do) is sending a True/False in the response.

or do I have to send a 404 Response ? ---> This is a simple get and 404 if notFound ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest writing  /api/v1/items/ping service

Comment: probably should be a HEAD request

Answer (score 5):

What do you mean by "isActive"? If this state (active: true/false) is part of your business logic then it should just be a property of the response. Always remember that REST (Representational state transfer) is about representing the current state of the application.

If you have to expose a state of an item, just include it in the response:

```
GET /api/items/1

{
    "name": "First item",
    "state": "inactive"
}
```

Alternatively, you could design a search like this: (I already URL-encoded the space.)

```
GET /api/items?state=active,name=First%20item
```

This should return an empty collection, if there is no item with an active state and a name "First item".

I would not put too much business logic into the routes, like a specific resource to check if an item is active because you are effectively constraining the client to one method on how to check, if an item is active. If you design your resources in a way, so the represent all the information that is available, the client can decide how to determine whether an item is active or not.